# How can there be fewer sessions than visitors in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, visitors, session

I found here a great [explanation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98350/google-analytics-user-vs-new-visitor-vs-returning-visitor) regarding the difference between users and visitors in GA, but somehow my stats (image attached) show 7330 New Visitors had 7312 Sessions (visits). How can there be fewer sessions than visitors, when it should be at least 1 session per 1 new visitor?

Excerpt from the relevant explanation I linked to above:

> When Google Analytics says "new visitors" or "returning visitors",
>   they mean "visits by new users", or "visits by returning users". For
>   example user A has visited your site before today and user B is new.
>   Each visits 2 times on the same day separated by at least 30 minutes:
>
> User A Visit 1: Returning user, Returning visitor Visit 2: Returning
>   visitor User B Visit 1: New user, New visitor Visit 2: Returning
>   visitor You will have:
>
> 2 Users 1 New User 1 Returning User 4 Visitors 1 New Visitors 3
>   Returning visitors New users will always be the same as new visitors,
>   but each user may may multiple visits so the total number of visitors
>   may be greater than the total number of users. Similarly, returning
>   visitors may be greater than the number of returning users.

[image: 7330 new visitors having 7312 sessions]